# How to call a method that is defined in the main class('_MyHomePageState()') from a onPressed of a Flat Button defined in a another class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the main class `_MyHomePageState()` where the scaffold is defined for the homepage and I have defined very widget that will go into the scaffold in a new class. Now I have to call a function/method that is defined in the main class from the `onPressed` of the FlatButton that is in the main class.

The function that is in the main class triggers the BottomSheet, the code for the bottom sheet is written in a new dart file.

When I write the Flat button code inside the scaffold normally and call the function it does trigger the bottom sheet.

Here's the code snippet:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  ///This below is the function
  void openBottomSheet() {
    var sheetController = scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showBottomSheet((context) => BottomSheetWidget());
    sheetController.closed.then((value) {
      print("Bottom Sheet Closed");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello,World"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TopMenu(),
            ButtonClass(),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the button class:

```
class ButtonClass extends StatefulWidget {
  _ButtonClassState createState() => _ButtonClassState();

}

class _ButtonClassState extends State<ButtonClass> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Container(color: Colors.blue, child: Text("Hello,World")),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width:100,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                ///And I am trying to call that function here, but is not working
                _MyHomePageState().openBottomSheet();
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a function parameter in your child Button Class and then pass the desired function to it from your parent class _MyHomePageState.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  ///This below is the function
  void openBottomSheet() {
    var sheetController = scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showBottomSheet((context) => BottomSheetWidget());
    sheetController.closed.then((value) {
      print("Bottom Sheet Closed");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello,World"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TopMenu(),
           ButtonClass(onPressed: ()=> openBottomSheet() ),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}



class ButtonClass extends StatefulWidget {
   Function onPressed;
   ButtonClass({this.onPressed});
  _ButtonClassState createState() => _ButtonClassState();

}

class _ButtonClassState extends State<ButtonClass> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Container(color: Colors.blue, child: Text("Hello,World")),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width:100,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => widget.onPressed,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you have to pass that function from main page to button.. something like this

```
    class ButtonClass extends StatefulWidget {
    final Function onPress;
    const ButtonClass({this.onPress});
           //...
           //...
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: onPress,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        ),
       );
      }
        }
```

and in your main class call it

```
ButtonClass(onPress: ()=>openBottomSheet())
```